# Trying to add up data from CoreData and show the 3 types of results

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift4

I have an app that is keeping track of Persons. Each Person can have multiple statements. Those statements can be negative or positive numbers. What I am trying to do is come up with 3 totals.

1. Carl = total:-20
   A. Lunch: -5
   B. Dinner: -15
2. Lynda = total: +9
   A. Ballgame: +10
   B. Game: -1

   1. The total for all persons and all of their statements (-11). 2. A total for all positive statements(+10). 3. A total for all negative statements(-21).

Before I was using the cellForRowAt function to add up my data. This worked, but gave me unexpected results when I pulled the tableview up or down.

This is what I was using inside cellForRowAt

```
let person = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects![indexPath.row]
```

And I would cycle through the data wtih a for loop

```
for amount in person.statement! {}
```

I have been trying something like this but keep getting errors:

```
 for person in fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects! as [Person?] {
        print("\(person!.name!) is the user name")

        for amount in (person?.statement!)! {
            print("\(Double(truncating: (amount as! Statement).amountOwed!)) amount to check")
        }
    }
```